# How to save file in java?

Tags: java

I've developed an interface with a menubar and a text area. I've included open, new, save and save as options under 'File'. When i open a text file, the content of the file appears in the text area in this way

```
Hello
Good
morning
```

When i edit the content, click on save and if i open the text file(not in the interface), the content in the file looks something like this

```
Hello good morning how are you......
```

All the text is saved in the above format instead of

```
 Hello
 good
 morning
 how
 are 
 you
 ......
```

How can i avoid this?

Comment: `BufferedReader#readLine()` eats newlines. Perhaps you're using that? In any way, your question is too broad. Please run your code step by step, naildown the root cause and ask about that instead, along with some concrete code.

Comment: open it in a better text editor then notepad.... have you tried **notepad++**?

Comment: @ven you should add the code, which creates and writes to the file.

Answer (score 2):

**Look at the data you are saving character by character.**

Different operating systems use different character sequences for the end of the line.  Windows uses the `\r\n` sequence.  Linux uses `\n` alone, and I believe Mac uses `\r` alone.  Since you're working with text files, you will need to decide which format you wish to use.

At the point at which you save the file, walk through the String you are saving and print out each character.  You may find that you're not even writing any of these characters.  This all depends on the method you are using to write the `String` in the text area to the file.

Comment: or just use println instead of print -_-